# Prepare Sql statement and store in variable

Tags: mysql, vb.net, prepared-statement

I have a problem which i have simplified below.
I have a sql statement which is filled in by parameters i.e Prepared statement. Is it possible to get the final prepared statement and store it in a variable

here is what i am trying to do but its not working

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE `users` SET `email` = ?email", con)
cmd.Prepare()
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", "newEmail")
```

Now here i tried doing this

```
Dim finalQuary As String = cmd.CommandText.ToString
```

I did that hoping to get this in the variable:

```
"UPDATE `users` SET `email` = theEmailAddress"
```

but instead i got the original unprepared statement i.e

```
UPDATE `users` SET `email` = ?email
```

i hope you understand my problem. if I'm not clear please tell me

Comment: You *must* have to specify the name, data type,length(size) of each parameter in the statement to be prepared before you call the `Prepare()` method. *Prepare returns an error if these conditions are not met.*

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement is done MySQL-side at execution time.  You're basically trying to get the code of a function with all of the parameters replaced by the values provided.  Unless VB.NET is emulating the prepared statement (which I'm guessing it's not), or MySQL has an API to return an interpolated string (which to my knowledge it does not), you can't get an interpolated-string-version of the query.

Answer (score 0):

use `@` instead of `?`

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE `users` SET `email` = @email", con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", "newEmail")
```

Comment: same problem, i get the original query

Comment: can you remove `cmd.Prepare()` and try it again.